# Date checking - cannot read property "0" from undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to use an array of dates to either return 'true' or 'false' when compared to the current date. However, I get the error message of 'Cannot read property "0" from undefined'. I've tried researching this but still can't figure out what the issue is. Does anyone know what the error may be? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you - Matt

```
const list = [{start:new Date("April 21, 2017, 13:00"), end: new Date("April 21, 2017, 15:29")}]
var timeDateNow = new Date();
for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; ++i)

{       
     var timeDateNow = new Date();

    if (timeDateNow >= list.start[i] && timeDateNow < list.end[i])
{
    return true;
}

else

{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `list[i].start` and `list[i].end`

Comment: From me and every other person trying to answer people's questions for reputation you should really accept answers to questions that helped you solve your issues, you have 10 or more open questions that have never been marked as answered which is unfair as I highly doubt none of these open questions haven't solved your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the `list` array incorrectly.

Try changing to

```
if (timeDateNow >= list[i].start && timeDateNow < list[i].end)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you've used `list.start[i]` it should be `list[i].start` to correctly access the array.

fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/hnuwcfbk/ check console for output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have placed 'i' at wrong place

```js
var list = [{start:new Date("April 28, 2017, 03:00"), end: new Date("April 28, 2017, 15:29")}]
var timeDateNow = new Date();
for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; ++i)

{       
     var timeDateNow = new Date();

    if (timeDateNow >= list[i].start && timeDateNow < list[i].end)
{
    console.log('true')
}

else

{
   console.log('false')
}
}
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't catch that. Appreciate the help!